# Why is my party not being created and saved to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my parameters whitelisted and when I look at the output of party_params I see that they are permitted but when I got to save the instance into the database it gives me a rollback transaction in the console. I've tried just create, create then save, new then save. Is there something I am missing?

```
#controller
class PartiesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @party = Party.new
    end

    def create
        @party = Party.create(party_params)
        redirect_to party_path(@party)
    end

    private

    def party_params
        params.require(:party).permit(
            :name,
            :trainer_id,
            :pokemon1_id
        )
    end
end

#model
class Party < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :trainer
    belongs_to :pokemon
    
    validates :name, presence: true
end

#view

<h1>Create a New Pokemon Party</h1>
<p>Select 6 Pokemon</p>

<%= form_for(@party) do |f| %>

    <label>Party Name:</label>
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br>

    <label>Trainer Name:</label>
    <%= collection_select(:party, :trainer_id, Trainer.order(:id), :id, :name, include_blank: true) %><br>

    <label>Pokemon:</label>
    <%= collection_select(:party, :pokemon1_id, Pokemon.order(:id), :id, :nickname, include_blank: false) %><br>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#schema
  create_table "parties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "pokemon1_id"
    t.integer "trainer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Comment: Why do you have ` :pokemon1_id`? I guess that should be just `:pokemon_id`?

Comment: I am trying to make a party have up to 6 pokemon. I don't know if the relationship may need to be changed to have a many-to-many relatioship and so that may be the problem. However, when i place a pry in the controller action I see all of the attributes assigned correctly but it does not generate an :id for the party.

Comment: The best way for you to know what is the problem here is using `pry`, go to your controller and add the `binding` on the first line of `create` method, then instantiate a new party, and before saving check using `@party.valid?` if you got `false` then you can `@party.error.messages` and see what is the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with the models. If you want a party to be able to include multiple pokemon you need to place the foreign key in the other model:

```
class Party < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :trainer
  has_many :pokemons # references the pokemons.party_id column
end
```

```
class Pokemon  < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :party # pokemons needs a `party_id` column
end
```

```
class AddPartyToPokemons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :pokemons, :party, null: false, foreign_key: true
    remove_column :parties, :pokemon1_id
  end
end
```

This is very simplefied and assumes that Pokemon is an individual Pokemon and not the entire species and can only belong to a single party. Otherwise you need a many-to-many assocation with a join table/model.

In your controller you need to check if creating the record was actually successful and respond accordingly:

```
class PartiesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @party = Party.new
    end

    def create
        @party = Party.new(party_params)
        if @party.save
            redirect_to @party
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    private

    def party_params
        params.require(:party).permit(
            :name,
            :trainer_id,
            pokemon_ids: []
        )
    end
end
```

If the user input is invalid this will render the `app/parties/new.html.erb` view and respond with it.

While you could use pry or byebug to step into the controller and check the errors you want to [display the validation errors](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views) to the user in the view anyways so that they know what to actually do to correct the form:

```
<h1>Create a New Pokemon Party</h1>
<p>Select 6 Pokemon</p>

<%= form_for(@party) do |f| %>
  <% if @party.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@party.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this party from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @article.errors.each do |error| %>
      <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <% 
    # group labels and inputs in an element instead of abusing BR tags 
    # this lets you style the content with CSS
  -%>
  <div class="field">
    <%# use f.label as it sets the `for=` attribute which is important for screen readers -%>
    <%= f.label :name, 'Party Name:' %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :trainer_id, 'Trainer Name:' %>
    <%# call the helper on the form builder to bind the input to the model -%>
    <%= f.collection_select(:trainer_id, Trainer.order(:id), :id, :name, include_blank: true) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pokemon_ids, 'Pokemon:' %>
    <%# call the helper on the form builder to bind the input to the model -%>
    <%= f.collection_select(:pokemon_ids, Pokemon.order(:id), :id, :nickname, include_blank: false, multiple: true) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Note `f.collection_select(:pokemon_ids, ...)`. This is a special setter/getter is generated by `has_many :pokemons`.

Comment: Restricting a party to 6 pokemon(s?) is really an entire separate question of its own and can be done with a custom validation.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up making a many-to-many relationship and that solved the problem of saving onto the database. I guess I wasn't paying too much attention to what I actually needed from that relationship.